# JQuantLib Option Volatility

Tags: java, quantlib, jquantlib

I have tried running through C++ documentation for finding *Options volatility*, that's embedded into the price of an option. However to my dismay, I couldn't use it.

Upon investigation and backtracking, I could see that the `ImpliedVolatilityHelper` class does the required job, however existence of other methods like `VanillaOption.impliedVolatility()` method
are making me confused on the correct usage. In addition, JQuantLib documentation is very much non existent.

Any help on how to use the correct method?

I see the QuantLib is easy to use in Python wish to move to python. Any suggestions?

Comment: I see you also posted this question [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/jquantlib/+question/288872).

Comment: Yes. I need an answer. Still i do not see an answer/suggestion either here or there. Thanks for sharing the link.